# How Can I create a custom Class in Dataflavor?

Tags: java

```
private static final DataFlavor flavors[] = { DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor};
```

I want to create a custom dataflavor with custom class just like code below except string class. I want to set a class created by me.

```
class MyClass extends DataFlavor
{   
    public MyClass MyClass() 
    {       

    }   
}

static DataFlavor flavor1 = new DataFlavor(MyClass.class, null);
```

How do I create a class which is suitable in Dataflavor?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dataflavor.html) is how according to a tutorial in the official documentation for this class! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own YourDataFlavor to extends DataFlavor,and create constructor method  whatever want.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataFlavor myFlavor = new DataFlavor(MyAwesomeClassThatTheWorldShouldShare.class, null);
```

You would, of course, be better extending from DataFlavor, makes like a million times eaiser

```
class MyClass extends DataFlavor
{
    public MyClass MyClass()
    {
      super(JavaClassToBeRepresented.class, null);
    }   
}

static DataFlavor flavor1 = new MyClass();
```

Comment: I want to send custom data type with class in dnd. I created a class and put in dataflavor. But none of them returned. How can i make a class return a custom data type?

Comment: I have edited my question. How can i set property or data type in myclass?